# ComboBox doesn't load blank value when using ComboBox.SelectedItem = -1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, combobox

I have a comboBox which correctly loads the List of data that I've queried from the DB, my only issue is that I can't seem to make it load blank and force the user to select from the list (which then pushes the actions under the SelectedIndexChanged() method).  Through my searches, I've seen where I can simply change the SelectedItem value to -1, and that should load the comboBox on a null choice, but when I use this code I see no difference.  The comboBox still loads the list correctly, but the first entry in the list is still displayed.

```
private void loadPatientList()
    {
        comboBox_PatientSelect.DataSource = patientList.Distinct().ToList();
        comboBox_PatientSelect.DisplayMember = "displayFullName";
        comboBox_PatientSelect.ValueMember = "patientID";
        comboBox_PatientSelect.SelectedItem = -1;
    }
```

I appreciate any help - and will be happy to provide more information if needed.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `SelectedIndex`. So make it `comboBox_PatientSelect.SelectedIndex = -1;`

From MSDN:

> This property indicates the zero-based index of the currently selected item in the combo box list. Setting new index raises the SelectedIndexChanged event.
>
> SelectedIndex, SelectedValue, and FormattingEnabled are related as follows:
>
> - If FormattingEnabled is **false**, SelectedIndex will not be set to -1 when SelectedValue is blank.
> - If FormattingEnabled is **true**, SelectedIndex will be set to -1 when SelectedValue is blank.
>
> > ### NOTE:
> >
> > **To deselect the currently selected item, set the SelectedIndex to -1. You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.**

Comment: I tried SelectedIndex originally, but kept getting an error regarding the Index being out of range (probably related to the "Note" at the bottom of MSDN's explanation).  Is there no way to work around this when the ComboBox is a data-bound item?

Comment: If it's data-bound you'll have to either keep a blank record in your source data, or insert a blank one when you populate the combobox.